# applying arrayfun on n-dimensional matrixes

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix-indexing

i need your help in solving the following problem:

how can i generalize the following for any n dimensional array:

```
reshape(arrayfun(@(x,y)sprintf('%d,%d',x,y),C{:},'un',0),size(M));
```

M is my matrix and C is my matrix of indexes of M.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the number of dimensions in the arguments to `arrayfun` per se, but the number of arguments themselves - which happens in your example to correspond to the number of dimensions each argument has. You therefore need to pass it a function that accepts `varargin`, which still works on an anonymous function:

```
reshape(arrayfun(@(varargin)sprintf(strjoin(repmat('%d',size(varargin)),','),varargin{:}),C{:},'un',0),size(M));
```

Comment: what i need to pass as varargin ?

Comment: `varargin` is the list of input arguments to the anonymous function that is the first argument to `arrayfun`. The arguments that are passed to that anonymous function are the next arguments to `arrayfun`, i.e. the arrays contained in each cell of `C`. That's how your original example works too, just with a fixed number (2) of elements in `C` required to be able to pass as arguments to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

This function gave me a lot of headache.

For functions like

```
f1 = @(x1,x2) x1*x2
```

You can do

```
output = arrayfun(f1,x1,x2);
```

where x1 and x2 are input columns.

However, if you're doing a generalized program, where `f1` could have any number of inputs and you need a generalized input matrix like X, you'll need, for example

```
f1 = @(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) 2*x1+4*x2+10*x3+0.2*x4+x5;

output = arrayfun(f1,num2cell(X,1){:});
```

where `X` represents a matrix with 5 columns representing `x1` through `x5`
For example:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
     6, 7, 8, 9, 0;];
```